# Time Series & Forecast - Daily Data for 7.5 months

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, zoo, arima

I have daily sales data between 1/1/2017 and 10/15/2017. My first question is that I was trying to set the time series with the following command:

`marketing = ts(df$Total_Sales_Spend, start=c(2017,1,1), frequency = 365)`

However, when I try to decompose the TS, I am getting the following error:
`time-series has no or less than 2 periods`

I understand that it's because I don't have at least two years of data. So in this case what can I do?

Also, I'd like to forecast the daily sales numbers for the second half of October (16 days). How may I do that in this case? I wasn't able to set it up with *zoo* and *arima*.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that that instruction gives that error? That error is thrown when you decompose a time series, no when you create one.

Comment: You are absolutely right, my bad. The questions hold though.

Comment: To forecast you will need to fit a model. Then call functions like `predict` or `forecast::forecast` on the fitted model. But that is a very broad theme. *Very* broad.